# Can we disable MemberInfo and Subscription Centre restrictions?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have previously disabled this in the past for clients, however my most recent request to Salesforce have responded saying the only way to achieve this is by disabling CAN-SPAM on the account. Is this correct? If yes, does this have any other implications?

Comment: We did it like you just a few weeks ago in a customer project. I have never heard of an option support is describing in your case.

Comment: Do you mean the physical address check and the preference center check?  That is part of CAN-SPAM so if you turn it off you are disabling CAN-SPAM validation

Comment: @EazyE yep that’s what I’m referring to, but I want to know does CANSPAM have any other features that would be lost if disabled?

Comment: You're basically circumventing CAN-SPAM personalization string checks and allowing users to send emails without the boxes ticked for CAN-SPAM compliance. It's not an all or nothing as each of the checks can be disabled independently - ask for the "PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_SUPPRESSION" Business Rule to be enabled or have the "UNSUB_LINK_CHECK" and "PROFILE_LINK_CHECK"  Business Rules disabled. If you're a user in the United States, this is pretty dangerous, but I'm not aware of any "other features" that you're disabling, other than these safeguards.